# Display 3D-Object with COCOS3D on top of AR-View

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I work on an app, which scans an image and shows you a 3D-Object or a video on top of the image target. Normal AR-App. For that AR stuff I usw the Vuforia SDK. The problem is, that the Vuforia SDK don't support animated 3D-Objects and for that I use cocos3d.

So I created a basic cocos3d app and included my vuforia stuff for the AR. This works good and the app displays normal 3D-Objects and videos. This was the background, now the problem.

The first view I have is my camera view, which scans the images. If I scan now a specified target, I want to show an animated 3D-Object. For that, I display the cocos3d view on top of the AR-View. The cocos3d view is transparent and is displayed on top of the AR-View (tested this with a simple button in the cocos3d view).

The problem is, that I'am not able to display a animated 3D-Object. I tested some options but none of them worked because I don't really have an idea how to do that. My current code:

```
CCDirector *director = CCDirector.sharedDirector;
EAGLViewCC *glView = [EAGLViewCC viewWithFrame:[window bounds] pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES];

[director setOpenGLView:glView];

[window addSubview:director.openGLView];
```

After that I have a layer and add the test scene to my layer (Standard from the example). But than I don't know how to display it. It tried this:

```
[director pushScene:scene];
```

but no luck. In the example, they use this code to show the object (viewController is of type "CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController").

```
[viewController runSceneOnNode: mainLayer];
```

Why don't I use the viewController? Because I couldn't get the view transparent. So how do I get the 3D-Object displayed in my view? What do I have to do? Am I completely wrong?